# Mapping exception between nullables?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm getting this exception:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>   FollowUpActivityDTO -> Nullable`1
>   LEST.Model.FollowUpActivityDTO -> System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>
> Destination path:
>   List`1[0]
>
> Source value:
>
> class FollowUpActivityDTO {
>     Id: 75e83860-65e4-11e5-9a90-382c4ab9e433
>     Timestamp: 28/09/2015 11:28:55
>     StartTimestamp: 28/09/2015 15:26:00
>     DueTimestamp: 28/09/2015 15:26:00
>     ClosingTimestamp: 28/09/2015 15:26:00
>     Matter: elasticsearch - copia - copia.jar
>     Comment: Archive
>     Status: open
>     BacklogStatus: unknown
>   }

```
{Trying to map FollowUpActivityDTO to Nullable`1.}
```

It raises when I perform:

```
return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<LEST.Model.FollowUpActivityDTO>, List<Domain.FollowUpActivity>>(dtos);
```

This is destination class:

```
public class FollowUpActivity
{
    private String id;              // Generated on server
    private DateTime? creationDate;
    private DateTime? startDate;
    private DateTime? dueDate;
    private DateTime? closingDate;
    private String matter;
    private String comment;
    private FollowUpActivityStatus status;
    private FollowUpActivityBacklogStatus backlogStatus;

    private List<MetaInfoValue> metainfos;
    private List<MetaResource> resources;
```

And this is the source class:

```
 public class FollowUpActivityDTO
{
    public FollowUpActivityDTO();

    public string BacklogStatus { get; set; }
    public string ChannelId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ClosingTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Matter { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }
```

And mapping profile:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<LEST.Model.FollowUpActivityDTO, Domain.FollowUpActivity>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.CreationDate, opts => opts.Ignore()) //opts.MapFrom(s => s.Timestamp.HasValue ? s.Timestamp.Value : DateTime.MinValue))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.StartDate, opts => opts.Ignore()) //opts.MapFrom(s => s.StartTimestamp.HasValue ? s.StartTimestamp.Value : DateTime.MinValue))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.DueDate, opts => opts.Ignore()) //opts.MapFrom(s => s.DueTimestamp.HasValue ? s.DueTimestamp.Value : DateTime.MinValue))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.ClosingDate, opts => opts.Ignore()) //opts.MapFrom(s => s.ClosingTimestamp.HasValue ? s.ClosingTimestamp.Value : DateTime.MinValue));
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Status, opts => opts.UseValue<Domain.FollowUpActivityStatus>(Domain.FollowUpActivityStatus.Open))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.BacklogStatus, opts => opts.UseValue<Domain.FollowUpActivityBacklogStatus>(Domain.FollowUpActivityBacklogStatus.Work));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Test for testing this mapping:

```
namespace Tests
{
[TestFixture]
public class Mapping
{

    [SetUp]
    public void initialize()
    {
        Core.Mappings.AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
    }

    [Test]
    public void configutation()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid<Core.Mappings.Profiles.FollowUpActivityProfile>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void followUpActivityDTOToDOMAIN()
    {
        LEST.Model.FollowUpActivityDTO dto = new LEST.Model.FollowUpActivityDTO()
        {
            Id = new Guid().ToString(),
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
            StartTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
            DueTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ClosingTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Matter = "Matter",
            Comment = "Comment",
            Status = "open",
            BacklogStatus = "work",
            Metainfos = new System.Collections.Generic.List<LEST.Model.MetaInfoValueDTO>()
        };

        Domain.FollowUpActivity domain = new Domain.FollowUpActivity();
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<LEST.Model.FollowUpActivityDTO, Domain.FollowUpActivity>(dto, domain);

        domain.Should().NotBeNull();
        domain.Id.Should().Be(dto.Id);
    }
}
}
```

Take a look on:

```
Domain.FollowUpActivity domain = new Domain.FollowUpActivity();
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<LEST.Model.FollowUpActivityDTO, Domain.FollowUpActivity>(dto, domain);
```

Now I works. However, if I code as follow, it crashes:

```
Domain.FollowUpActivity domain = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<LEST.Model.FollowUpActivityDTO, Domain.FollowUpActivity>(dto);
```

I'm figuring out the problem is over the constructors of my Destination class then:

```
namespace Domain
{
public enum FollowUpActivityStatus
{
    Open,
    Closed,
    Delegated
}

public enum FollowUpActivityBacklogStatus
{
    Work,
    Sprint        
}

public class FollowUpActivity
{
    private String id;              // Generated on server
    private DateTime? creationDate;
    private DateTime? startDate;
    private DateTime? dueDate;
    private DateTime? closingDate;
    private String matter;
    private String comment;
    private FollowUpActivityStatus status;
    private FollowUpActivityBacklogStatus backlogStatus;

    private List<MetaInfoValue> metainfos;
    private List<MetaResource> resources;

    #region Properties

    public String Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public DateTime? CreationDate
    {
        get { return creationDate; }
        set { creationDate = value; }
    }

    public DateTime? StartDate
    {
        get { return startDate; }
        set { startDate = value; }
    }

    public DateTime? DueDate
    {
        get { return dueDate; }
        set { dueDate = value; }
    }

    public DateTime? ClosingDate
    {
        get { return closingDate; }
        set { closingDate = value; }
    }

    public FollowUpActivityStatus Status
    {
        get { return status; }
        set { status = value; }
    }

    public FollowUpActivityBacklogStatus BacklogStatus
    {
        get { return backlogStatus; }
        set { backlogStatus = value; }
    }

    public String Matter
    {
        get { return matter; }
        set { matter = value; }
    }

    public String Comment
    {
        get { return comment; }
        set { comment = value; }
    }

    public List<MetaInfoValue> Metainfos
    {
      get { return metainfos; }
      set { metainfos = value; }
    }

    public List<MetaResource> Resources
    {
        get { return resources; }
        set { resources = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public FollowUpActivity()
        : this(null, null)
    {

    }

    public FollowUpActivity(String matter, String comment = null, params Domain.MetaInfoValue[] metainfos)
        : this(DateTime.Now, matter, comment, metainfos)
    {

    }

    public FollowUpActivity(DateTime creationDate, String matter, String comment = null, params Domain.MetaInfoValue[] metainfos)
        : this(creationDate, matter, new List<MetaResource>(), comment, metainfos)
    {

    }

    public FollowUpActivity(DateTime creationDate, String matter, List<MetaResource> resources, String comment = null, params Domain.MetaInfoValue[] metainfos)
        : this(creationDate, matter, FollowUpActivityBacklogStatus.Work, new List<MetaResource>(), comment, metainfos)
    {

    }

    public FollowUpActivity(DateTime creationDate, String matter, FollowUpActivityBacklogStatus backlogStatus, List<MetaResource> resources, String comment = null, params Domain.MetaInfoValue[] metainfos)
        : this(creationDate, null, null, null, matter, FollowUpActivityStatus.Open, backlogStatus, new List<MetaResource>(), comment, metainfos)
    {

    }

    public FollowUpActivity(DateTime? creationDate, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? dueDate, DateTime? closingDate, String matter, FollowUpActivityStatus status, FollowUpActivityBacklogStatus backlogStatus, List<MetaResource> resources, String comment = null, params Domain.MetaInfoValue[] metainfos)
    {
        this.id = String.Empty;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
        this.closingDate = closingDate;
        this.matter = matter;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.status = status;
        this.backlogStatus = backlogStatus;

        this.metainfos = new List<MetaInfoValue>(metainfos);
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    #endregion

}
}
```

However, I don't know why does it crashes using the second approach... Someone knows why?
Thanks for all.